# dplyr: Can a function called inside mutate find the element of a column from current row

Tags: r, vectorization, dplyr

I have a very large data frame and a set of adjustment coefficients that I wish to apply to certain years, with each coefficient applied to one and only one year. The code below tries, for each row, to select the right coefficient, and return a vector containing `dat` in the unaffected years and `dat` times that coefficient in the selected years, which is to replace `dat`.

```
year <- rep(1:5, times = c(2,2,2,2,2))
dat  <- 1:10
df <- tibble(year, dat)
adjust = c(rep(0, 4), rep(c(1 + 0.1*1:3), c(2,2,2)))
df %>% mutate(dat = ifelse(year < 5, year, dat*adjust[[year - 2]]))
```

If I get to do this, I get the following error:

```
Evaluation error: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex.
```

I am pretty sure this is because the extraction operator `[[` treats `year` as the entire vector year rather than the year of the current row, so there is then a vectorized subtraction, whereupon `[[`  chokes on the vector-valued index.

I know there are many ways to solve this problem. I have a particularly ugly way involving nested ifelse’s working now. My question is, is there any way to do what I was trying to do in an R- and dplyr- idiomatic way?  In some ways this seems like a filter or group_by problem, since we want to treat rows or groups of rows as distinct entities, but I have not found a way of doing so that is any cleaner.

It seems like there are some functions which are easier to define or to think of as row-by-row rather than as the product of entire vectors. I could produce a single vector containing the correct adjustment for each year, but since the number of rows per year varies, I would still have to apply a multi-valued conditional test to construct that vector, so the same problem arises.

Or doesn’t it?

Comment: How do you map `adjust` to `year`? You have five different years but only three `adjust` values.

Comment: year maps to year for year less than -- well, actually, less than 3,not 2. Let me fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `[` instead of `[[` for vector indexing; And also `year - 2` produces negative index which will further give problems; If you want to map `year` to `adjust` by index positions, you can use `replace` with a `mask` that indicates the `year` to be modified:

```
df %>% 
    mutate(dat = {
        mask = year > 2; 
        replace(year, mask, dat[mask] * adjust[year[mask] - 2])
    })
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   year1  dat1
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1   1.0
# 2     1   1.0
# 3     2   2.0
# 4     2   2.0
# 5     3   5.5
# 6     3   6.6
# 7     4   8.4
# 8     4   9.6
# 9     5  11.7
#10     5  13.0
```

Comment: Thanks Psidom!  That replace function is very handy -- I am surprised that I have not run across it before. I was just trying to write something similar using left_join.  If I get around to it, not guaranteed, I'll benchmark them against each other and post the results here.